# getting error while referencing by id inside ngif

Tags: angular

I hope you can help me with the right way of doing this. I have a div with 3 labels, everyone of them is shown in a different condition, and after that I have another div that has 3 labels that shows different things based on the first div, but I'm getting errors. I know that when an element is under ngif is not rendered by angular, but at some point I make the condition true, so what would be the way of doing this?

```
<div>
   <label>Direccion: &nbsp;</label>
   <label *ngIf="selectedPerson.localPersonas?.length === 0">No hay locales registrados</label>
   <label *ngIf="selectedPerson.localPersonas?.length === 1">{{selectedPerson.localPersonas[0].direccion}}</label>
   <mat-form-field *ngIf="selectedPerson.localPersonas?.length > 1">
       <mat-label>Selecciona una direccion</mat-label>
       <mat-select #locales>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let local of selectedPerson.localPersonas" [value]="local"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedPerson.localPersonas[0]" ngDefaultControl>
                    {{local.direccion}}</mat-option>
       </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div>
   <label>Telefonos: &nbsp;</label>
   <label *ngIf="selectedPerson.localPersonas?.length === 0">No hay telefonos registrados</label>
   <label *ngIf="selectedPerson.localPersonas?.length === 1">{{selectedPerson.localPersonas[0].direccion}}</label>
   <mat-form-field *ngIf="locales && locales.value.localPersonas.length > 1">
       <mat-label>Selecciona un telefono</mat-label>
       <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let telefono of locales.value.telefonoLocals" [value]="telefono"
                    [(ngModel)]="locales.value.telefonoLocals[0].numero" ngDefaultControl>
                    {{telefono.numero}}</mat-option>
       </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

The problem raises when in the first div, the reference "locales" doesn't exist after the first run, so when I make an ngif based on that reference the error is shown. But after a function call on my ts, localPersonas array is not undefined and thus the reference "locales"is available. What is the way of accomplish this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If selectedPerson and locales are the main properties of your template, then you could add a ng-container around all your tags.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedPerson && locales">

...your tags here...

</ng-container>
```

With this 2 conditions, you'll be sure your main properties are available.

Comment: but locales is not always present, it will only be present if selectedPerson.localPersonas length > 1